# Find method unique values does not automatically appear on column

Tags: excel, vba

I have used the find method to compare two columns (A and B)in different sheets. column A is the updated column while column B is the copied column.the code will loop through and columns and find for match cases. If there is a unique value in column A, it will copy it to column B. I have managed to code it but the unique value does not automatically appear in column B. Only when i click on the unique value cell of column A would it then be copied into column B.

Does anyone know why it cannot update automatically?

Code in column A:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal target As Range)
If target.Column = 9 Then
fabric = ActiveCell.Value
Module4.ChkFabric (fabric)
End If

End Sub
```

I have used a module to copy to column B:

```
Sub ChkFabric(ByRef fabric As String)
Dim Rng, TgtC, ResC As Range
Dim PrePlan As Worksheet

Set PrePlan = Worksheets("Pre Master Plan")

With PrePlan
Set ResC = .Range("A:A")
endrow = .Cells(PrePlan.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With
With ResC
Set Rng = .Find(what:=Trim(fabric), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, 
searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False)
If Not Rng Is Nothing Then


Else
   PrePlan.Cells(endrow + 1, 1) = fabric
End If
End With


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a piece of code to fetch Unique value (Does not include a item if it has duplicates) from one column and write in to another

```
Sub uniq()
Dim cntOccur As Integer
Dim rowCount As Integer
Dim Checkcol As Integer, Targetcol As Integer
Dim currentRowValue As String
Dim currentRow As Integer, brow As Integer
Checkcol = 1 'Denotes A column
Targetcol = 2 'Denotes B column

rowCount = Cells(Rows.Count, Checkcol).End(xlUp).Row
brow = 0
  For currentRow = 1 To rowCount
      currentRowValue = Cells(currentRow, Checkcol).Value
' Check the number of occurrence of each and every cell in column A
      cntOccur = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A1:A" & rowCount), currentRowValue)
If cntOccur = 1 Then
brow = brow + 1
' If it is unique and has no duplicates then write in to B
Cells(brow, Targetcol).Value = currentRowValue
End If

Next
End Sub
```

Comment: this code only allows the comparison of two columns? because for my workbook i need to compare multiple columns to column B thats why i wrote the code in the module

Comment: Just extending the range in the below line from A1:A&rowcount to ur data range will make this work for your requirement.  Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(your data range), currentRowValue)

Comment: sorry my mistake, i meant column in multiple worksheets to compare to column B